# AJAX Как перейти на страницу возвращенную ajax запросом

Tags: ajax

AJAX Как перенаправить браузер на новую страницу,  возвращенную ajax  запросом

Comment: `document.write(ajaxRequest.responseText);`?

Answer (score 0):

узнал, что через window.location.href надо делать

```
$.ajax({
url : "/conf/index.php",
method : "POST",
data : {element_id: element_id,  element_name:element_name, element_date2:element_date2},
success : function(data){
if(success){
window.location.href = "/conf/index.php";
}
}
});
```